# Netflix error NSES-UHX on Wayland

Tags: snap, wayland, drm

When trying KWin Wayland session Netflix refuses to load any page with error NSES-UHX.

I tried asking their support but of course that didn't help and they completely ignored my initial suggestion about trying to help them debug it. Instead they said they [don't support Linux](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742) at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your session to KWin X11, it helped me. For now. But after relogging back into Wayland it works too now.